# Using Node.js async.series without anonymous functions

Tags: node.js

I'm learning Node and I'm coming to grips with the asynchronous nature of it. Now I want to use the `async` library to perform functions in a series. However, every example looks something like:

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        // do some stuff ...
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback){
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
});
```

So it uses anonymous functions. I would prefer to be able to use pre-defined functions (so I can re-use them without copy-pasting the code). So let's say I have a function defined like:

```
function doStuff(id){
    alert(id);
}
```

How can I add this function to the `series` above? Also, what to do about the task callback in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so...

```
function doStuff1(callback) {
  console.log('doStuff1');
  callback(null, 'one');
}
function doStuff2(callback) {
  console.log('doStuff2');
  callback(null, 'two');
}
function finally(err, results) {
  // Test error, use results
  // results == ['one', 'two']
}

async.series([doStuff1, doStuff2], finally);
```

Comment: Thanks, but one more sub-question: do I even need a callback in this case? can't I just use `function doStuff1(){console.log('dostuff1');}`?

Comment: Also,, doStuff needs a parameter to be passed to it. How do I do that here?

Comment: You must use the callback.  If you don't, the execution will stall.  The callback is how the async module knows to call the next function in the series.

Comment: Using anonymous functions brings with it the benefit of closures for passing variables.  It wouldn't be simple to pass a variable to doStuff1().  You could pass a variable from doStuff1() to doStuff2() if you use `async.waterfall` instead of `async.series`.

Comment: I don't see how you can neatly collect results from each of the doStuff calls to be used at the end of the waterfall without actually passing each result into *every* subsequent doStuff call, requiring the doStuff functions to pass them along via the callback. Doesn't it just end up with an ever-increasing list of parameters being collected and passed along, muddying the waters along the way? Async seems poorly suited to this kind of workflow.

Comment: @jarmod Updated the answer for you.  The `results` variable of the `finally` function collects the data returned from each function in the series.

Comment: @Daniel Ah, so async.series works differently from waterfall wrt the final results too. I was playing about with waterfall and it only seems to report the final callback result. In my case I need to pass values from one function to the next so I need to use waterfall, but waterfall doesn't accumulate the returned values like series, so now I'm back to passing them from function to function (unless I go with global variables or similar).